# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined, when try to catch API data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing Currency Converter application using ReactJS. The program is about convert from one currency to another. The application has one form consist of a field with submit button. Moreover it also has initial currency 'USD 10' as a default.

When user type the an abbreviation of currency (e.g.: KRW) in the field and click the submit button. There will be a result below the form that shows the result of the conversion from USD to KRW. If the user want to add more currency, another selection currency will be shown below "KRW" conversion result.

When I am trying to make function to show the result when user submit the abbreviation of currency in the field.

This is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'rates' of undefined
    at Currency.render (App.js:402)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15319)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15274)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:16262)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20279)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20320)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:20400)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21357)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:21267)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21241)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:21096)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20909)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11595)
    at App.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:336)
    at Object.App.addCurrency [as onSubmit] (App.js:34)
    at Form.handleSubmit (App.js:204)
```

And this is my code:

```
class Currency extends React.Component {
render() {
        const p = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="currency">
                {/*<span className="currencyText">&#x3C;Currency/&#x3E;</span>*/}
                <div className="currencyInfo">
                    <div>{"1 "+p.base + " = " }</div>
                    <div>{p.data.rates}</div> {/*this is (App.js:402)*/}

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Instead of that, If I code of Apps.js:402 like this:

```
<div>{p.data}</div>
```

and run the app, and check the console in chrome, the result for the line is empty.

The data that I mean is on the picture:

[image: console result]

And this is the result of console prop p:

[image: result of prop p in console.log]

Any solution for this, so that I can retrieve the data rates from the currency?

Comment: What is your prop `p`, can you console.log it out?  And how are you fetching it and passing it to the component?

Comment: What is p.data ? your rate is directly in props so it should be p.rates

Comment: You need to write it as `p.rates`, there is no `data` key in the props.

Comment: @sanjsanj I have update question above. I have put the result above. Please take a look. I do not really get what you mean "passing it to the component".

Comment: @Atul and @Gaurav Punjabi I have tried to code p.rates instead of p.data, but there is an error. `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {GBP}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at App.js:403)
 `

Comment: Your error says all, You can not pass object to element , you need to pass objects property. Can you post your rates object , or just open the object from your screen shot.

Comment: @Atul I see, I need to open the p.rates using JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you want some way to manage `loading` and `no-data` states in your component, depending on what your api returns when there is no data - you might have to manage it differently but that is also a scenario you should cover. Your data seems to be coming from a prop called `rates` not `data` which is an object with multiple keys.

I am not certain of the structure of your code, but this iteration and checking for loading/no-data states might also be done in the parent component.

```
    class Currency extends React.Component {
    render() {
            const p = this.props;
            const { rates = {} } = p;
            const hasData = Object.keys(rates).length > 0;
            return !p.loading ? (
                <div className="currency">
                    <div className="currencyInfo">
                        { hasData ?
                        <>
                          <div>{"1 "+p.base + " = " }</div>
                          {Object.entries(rates).map(([k, v]) => <div key={k}>{`${k}: ${v}`}</div>)}
                        </> : <p>No data available</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : <Loader />
        }
    }
```

In a parent component you could do something like:

```
    class ParentComp extends React.Component {
      public state = { loading: true, rates: {} };

      componentDidMount() {
        await this.fetchData(...); // could set loading to false on success
      }

      render() {
        const { rates = {} } = this.state;
        const hasData = Object.keys(rates).length > 0;
        return (
          !this.state.loading ?
            hasData ?
              Object.entries(rates).map(([k, v]) => <Currency key={k} name={k} value={v} ... />)
              : <p>No data available</p>
            : <Loader />
        );
      }
    }
```

Then in your child component:

```
class Currency extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return  (
      <div className='currency'>
        <div className='currencyInfo'>
            <div>{`${this.props.name}: ${this.props.value}`}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### CREDITS:

Thanks to @Codebling for pointing out the unnecessary addition of `v` (value) in the key's

Comment: Why did you include the value in the key? Curious, maybe I'm missing something. I just had the `k`/currency

Comment: @Codebling Yeah you are right no need for the value in there

Comment: Ok, I was curious, wasn't sure if my knowledge about how React uses keys was correct. I think just the currency name as key makes sense, since the value is prone to change, and then React can reuse the same DOM branch for Currency in that case, right? EDIT: just saw the credit haha, Really, no need, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Currency component is a Child and it has a Parent component.

Just initialise a value to your "data" before you pass it to child component.

```
const Child = props => {
  return(
    <div>
      Child
      {props.data.country}
    </div>
  )
}

const Parent = props => {

  // initiate state value to your variables that you are using.
  let [data, set_data] = useState(
    // this is where your error reside, you did not initiate a value.
    { country: 'abc'}
  );

  // api call
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://ip-api.com/json/24.48.0.1',{})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      set_data(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.config);
    });
  }, [])

  return(
    <div>
      Parent
      <Child data={data}></Child>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Parent;
```